# Restore images / pictures chunked into many files

Tags: images, restore

i am trying to find a way to restore image files that got chunked due to a restore from a broken harddrive.

> I am not sure if those files are in correct order or are at all recoverable as images.

What i want to archive is to:

1. Take the first image then
2. Check if it is a valid image and can be opened properly
3. **If not**

   - Append the second image to the first one (bit wise?)
   - Repeat 2 until an image is found

Is there any better way or an already existing tool that kind of helps with that?

The files for example look like that:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can concatenate files with `cat file1 file2 > file1and2` but ... it's very unusual for recovery to produce chunks that would work this way. Which recovery tool(s) did you use, how did the chunking happen and how would that appending work? For JPEG in particular, sometimes only thumbnails are restored, with the full image missing entirely. You can't restore a full image from a thumbnail. So recovery can only go back to the original data source and hope to find full files instead of... chunks

Comment: @frostschutz Thank you. I am aware it could be thumbnails. the restoration tool was long ago on a Windows machine with a broken HDD so i really don't know if there will be something useful. But i wanted to at least try seeing these chunks with such different file sizes

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `file` command to work out if it's a jpeg or not, and standard file operators to append.

Completely untested, but something like this might work:

```
for i in {1..23}
do
 THIS_TYPE="$( file Datei${i}.jpg )"
 if [ "${THIS_TYPE/JPEG}" != "$THIS_TYPE" ]
 then
  IMAGE="Datei${i}.jpg"
 else
  cat Datei${i}.jpg >> "$IMAGE"
 fi
done
```